# How can I determine which switch the Infiniband subnet manager is running on?

Tags: networking, infiniband

I recently inherited an Infiniband network containing multiple switches, and I know that one of these switches is running the subnet manager.  The rest supposedly have that feature turned off, or were never enabled.  The trouble is, I have no idea which one it is...

I'd like to replace the switch subnet manager with OpenSM running on a couple of my infrastructure servers.  Is there any way, short of logging into each switch individually, to determine which switch is running the SM?

Comment: Is there a LED that lights up when the switch is an SM?

Comment: Nope! (Just double checked the hardware, too. :) )  Would be a useful feature, I'll mention it to my Mellanox rep...

Comment: Which switches?

Answer (score 8):

If your infrastructure servers can run OpenSM, they may also have the OFED stack utilities installed as well. If the commands are available, `ibstat` will tell you the SM's LID. Then use the LID in `smpquery ND -L <LID>` to get the node description of the node running the SM.

Answer (score 6):

If you have an OFED installed in your system and the package `infiniband-diags` you can use the command **sminfo** to list running subnet managers in the Infiniband network:

```
~ # sminfo 
sminfo: sm lid 18 sm guid 0x0000000, activity count 55554951 priority 0 state 3 SMINFO_MASTER
```

It will list all known subnet managers for that node and the master subnet manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you reach your manager by IP address, you could look the ARP/MAC tables of your switches to find which IP address corresponds to your switch.

Answer (score 0):

First get the current SM manager info with `sminfo` and then query the node description with the `saquery` either by LID (local ID on your net), or GUID (global unique ID)

```
# sminfo
sminfo: sm lid 8 sm guid 0x24be05ffff8a5f71, activity count 53314 priority 14 state 3 SMINFO_MASTER
# saquery -O 8
login2 HCA-1
-OR
# saquery -U 0x24be05ffff8a5f71
login2 HCA-1
```

In case the node description doesn't say much, one can investigate the InfiniBand net with `ibnetdiscover  | less -S` and look for the GUID and the switch / port it is connected to.

For the list of all the Subnet Managers configured on the fabric, run `ibdiagnet` and check the ibdiagnet2.sm file (full path should be reported to the standart output).